# Can we use MS office com component on Mac OS?

Tags: com, ms-office

We can read and process Office documents (Word, Powerpoint) using OLE automation (Com programming) on Windows. But on Mac we have to use AppleScript which doesn't work without launching the software and opening the document. Can we use similar COM kind of approach on Mac for MS Office products ?

Comment: You are limited to AppleScript within OS X.

Answer (score 1):

After so much RnD I came to know the only way to automate MS Office one Mac is AppleScript.